# select where id == value and id != value mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have a table with values like this

```
listid   email
1        test@email.com
5        test@eamil.com
1        test123@email.com
```

From the above example you can see that the same email can show up in the email column with a different `listid`.

I want to return emails that have a `listid` of 1 but not not also have a `listid` of 5. In that case the only email returned would be test123@email.com.

For now I have

```
SELECT `email`,`listid` FROM `table` WHERE `emailaddress` LIKE '%@email%' AND `listid` != 5 AND `listid`=1
```

Of course this does not work because test@email does have a listid of 1 too. How can I exclude test@email from the results?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the `exists` operator:

```
SELECT `email`,`listid` 
FROM   `table` t
WHERE  `emailaddress` LIKE '%@email%' AND 
       `listid` = 1 AND
       NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                   FROM   `table` t2
                   WHERE  t1.`emailaddress` = t2.`emailaddress` AND
                          t2.`listid = 5)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a join:

```
SELECT t.email, t.listid
FROM `table` t
JOIN `table` t2 ON t.email = t2.email AND t2.listid != 5
WHERE t.listid = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way using conditional aggregation that's generally fast. The query selects emails with `listid` 1 or 5, and uses conditional aggregation to remove emails that have `listid` 5 and returns emails that only have `listid` 1.

```
select email
from mytable t
where email LIKE '%@email%'
and listid in (1,5)
group by email
having sum(listid = 5) = 0
```

This query can take advantage of an index on `listid`